# How to create horizontal button menu and submenu below navigation bar in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create horizontal button menu and submenu below navigation bar in bootstrap 4?

Kindly check the image below what I am trying to create:

[image]

[image]

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: So what did you tried? Where's your code?

Comment: The easiest way would be to find a styling library that does this for you.  Have a look at https://blog.bitsrc.io/11-material-design-ui-component-libraries-for-2018-b3d2c9962a2f

Comment: @ Robert Harvey,@ Christopher Dosin - Thanks for the reply. I don't have any idea about it and don't know where to start. <ul><li></li></ul> this is not sufficinet because I don't know what is it what is the concept behind it. How to adjust horizontal button <> in the starting and in the end. So it is very hard for me to achieve this. I am trying to learn the concept and searching it on the google.

Answer (score -1):

i think you want a vertical menu... if yes then you have to try this code
`<div class="btn-group-vertical">
  <button>add You button here</button>
...
</div>`